# How can I make this DAE import error go away?

Tags: ios, xcode, maya, collada, scenekit

After dragging a .DAE file into an XCode project for iPhone and then clicking on it, I see this error: [image: screenshot of Xcode error]

I don't see this error when I click .DAE files provided by Apple (I see a preview). This file was exported from Maya into COLLADA format. Do you have any ideas on how to get more information on this error? Do you have any ideas what might be causing this error?

I believe the original maya file will need to be altered and re-exported. However, I have little notion of what needs to be altered. The apple developer forums and the internet don't seem to have seen this error before and the animator and the rigger are also at a loss. I would love a hint!

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Do you see any log in the console when you try to open this file in Preview? What exporter did you use in Maya? the built-in one or the (better) openCollada one? (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCOLLADA/wiki/OpenCOLLADA-Tools)? (If you used the built-in exporter make sure it is exporting to dae and not fbx)

Comment: I've seen it when opening a exported file in Preview but in my case I could always open it in Xcode.

Comment: You should be able to open the file with anything that can parse XML to make sure you don't have any unclosed XML tags.  Unfortunately Collada exporters are all over the map in terms of compatibility. You could try round tripping the file to and from FBX using http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=22694909 to see if that identifies the problem

Comment: @Toyos Thanks! I see error logs in the console when I try to open the file in Preview. I'm checking with the designer about which exporter was used.

Comment: @theodox Good tip. It passes XML validation though. The FBX converter sounds like an unlikely hero, but it's worth a shot, thanks.

Comment: what errors do you see in the console? Is there more information than "The meshes in the document appear to be corrupted."?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar errors when exporting from Maya to DAE_FBX format.   The only way I was able to fix the error for import into Xcode was to save from Maya in FBX format, import into Cheetah3D, then export from Cheetah as a DAE.  I think there are bugs in how Maya exports DAE files (some appear to work for import into Xcode and some do not)

Answer (score 0):

If your scene contains blendshapes make sure that blendshape name and it's target mesh names are different.

One more issue can be cause because your scene has several shapes with the same name. For example Maya will create SurfaceShape for every new mesh.
So if your scene has SurfaceShape1 several times Xcode will report about bad mesh.
Solution just name Shape same name as mesh.